# Issue when run flet script on debian 10 on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, flet

## When I run code below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rWUi.png)

## Then I have error on terminal like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGMLz.png)

> I want to run a application building with flet framwork on python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.